# What is a Heavenly Word™?

Tags: knowledge, word-property

Inspired by JLee's original Word™/Phrase™ puzzles.

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Heavenly** word.
Use the examples to find the rule:

| Heavenly Words™ | Non-Heavenly Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| behead | decapitate |
| alabaster | gypsum |
| paywalls | purchase |
| inverse | contrary |
| unjoin | detached |
| Wolfram | Tungsten |
| sixtieth | seventieth |
| scenery | landscape |
| harvest | pick |

**What is the rule for determining what words are Heavenly, or Non-Heavenly?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Heavenly Word™ is one which

> contains letters which make [minor planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_planet) in our Solar system.

The Heavenly words

> behead - **Hebe**
>  alabaster-  **Astraea**
>  paywalls - **Pallas**
>  inverse - **Irene**
>  unjoin - **Juno**
>  Wolfram - **Flora**
>  sixtieth - **Thetis**
>  scenery -  **Ceres**
>  harvest - **Vesta**

These can all be found in the

> top 20 of this [list of minor planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_planets:_1%E2%80%931000)
>
>   Note: I updated from the original too general 'objects' which Benjamin Wang superbly found ones in the Non-Heavenly Word™ list when I referred to [List of Solar System objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Solar_System_objects_by_size).

Comment: Unfortunately, rot13(V jebgr n fpevcg gb purpx gung chepunfr pbagnvaf eurn, ghatfgra pbagnvaf fha, naq ynaqfpncr pbagnvaf frqan). It's a valiant effort though.

Comment: See https://pastebin.com/guav1cnR (table created with the help by https://wikitable2csv.ggor.de/)

Comment: @Benjamin - great check for the Non-Heavenly Words™. As all 9 vs 3 this post may still be relevant.

Comment: You have the general idea, but what are the specific objects? You have some associations wrong also.

Comment: Tom, you're a beast

Comment: Doesn't seventieth contain Thetis too?

Comment: ^ Amoz is right.